# javaws missing in Java 8 for Solaris

Tags: java, solaris, java-web-start

It looks like Oracle removed Java Web Start from Java 8 for Solaris. javaws isn't available anymore in Java 8u51.

From the [compatibility guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999476):

> The 64-bit binaries do not contain deployment tools such as Java Web
> Start and Java Plug-in, therefore desktop integration is no longer
> required.

What do they mean with "*required*"? It's *not possible* anymore. It's not possible to launch a Web Start application on Solaris with Java 8.

Does anyone know an alternate way (standard, no 3rd party stuff) to start a Web Start application on Solaris with Java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *"required"* means that, as the build for the java 8 for solaris is only available in 64bit version; therefore, the `Java Plug-in` and `Java Web Start` is no longer required to be installed as those two things are not available for 64-bit version of Solaris (you can check the link here https://www.java.com/en/download/help/webstart_64bits.xml).

I'm afraid I cannot found any way to run `Java Web Start` in "standard" way on Java 8. The easiest workaround for this is, of course, to install the older version of 32-bit java such as version 7.

Comment: So they should have worded as e. g. "futile" instead of "no longer required".