# does java 1.8.0_45 + support jnlp

Tags: javafx, java-web-start, jnlp

I have created a simple javafx application using netbeans. I build the application and it automatically gives me jar,jnlp and html file.I am trying to launch my jnlp file using javaws. After searching on web I enabled the jnlp extension in java control panel and also i edit the site list as well. Still I am not able to run the jnlp file. I am using Windows 7 with jre1.8.0_45. I have observed most of the examples present on the internet are using java version 1.6, please assist me if any one managed to launch the jnlp file.
thanks ina dvance

Comment: You said, "Still I am not able to run the jnlp file." but, I wonder what kind of errors you saw or didn't see.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, i can only see the java web start window and then it disappeared. It looks like a security issue. Java 1.8.0_45 is not allowing the jnlp files to launch. I need some certification license.

Comment: Did you enable the 'Java Console' in the Java Control Panel, 'Advanced' tab?  That may show something.  Also, that happens to be exactly what webstart does if you request a maximum heap that exceeds the amount of memory available on the client machine.

Comment: Oracle supply a trouble-shooting guide for [Applets and Java Web Start Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/plugin.html#BABDHAFC).  The guide is not comprehensive, but may provide some information that helps you track down your issue.  There is also some info (beware that some is a bit dated), from [Canadian Mind Products](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javawebstart.html) - I have not used that so am unsure of it's applicability.  The [JaNeLa tool](https://github.com/AlBundy33/JaNeLa) *might* help.

Comment: @david 
yes i have enabled the java console

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java WebStart is still supported. That is, unless you are on Solaris x64, there it was [killed for no understandable reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067297/javaws-missing-in-java-8-for-solaris).

You can find a tutorial about how to make a fully functional WebStart application including html and javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958019/embed-a-javafx-application-in-a-html-webpage).

Comment: I managed to run some javafx application via web browser. What I observed is, it is running those application which do not query any data from mysql. If they query data then I get the run time error like  com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:307). I get the console window with this kind of error. Looks like i need to verify my mysql connection. But i have not verified my connection ever before